# Increase the size of LVM after adding virtual disk space

Tags: linux, centos, lvm, fdisk

I have asked for a hard drive upgrade for my virtual server running centos 6.5

i can see that the space has been increased as /dev/sdb now is 214.7GB and used to be 150.3GB

```
root@webhost [/sys/class/block/sdb/device]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 85.9 GB, 85899345920 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 81920 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000390ad

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           2         501      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             502        3573     3145728   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3            3574       81920    80227328   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 204800 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x796ffff3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      143360   146800624   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/backup-lv0: 150.3 GB, 150319661056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 18275 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

root@webhost [/sys/class/block/sdb/device]#
```

as you can see the current lvm size is 140GB

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               backup
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  15
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               140.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              35839
  Alloc PE / Size       35839 / 140.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               9WAEQb-oEXG-QdJ0-MIK9-ZEu1-x176-U76PzS

root@webhost [/sys/class/block/sdb/device]#
```

how can i resize the lvm partition to match the drive's size?

Comment: lvextend -l 100%FREE [vg path], then a resize2fs [lv path] should do it

Comment: @Chopper3 as you can see from vgdisplay command above the Free PE/Size is 0. lvextend doesn't increase as it thinks that size is already at max

Comment: WHat is the result of `vgs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand `sdb1` to cover all available disk space. Then, you can `pvresize /dev/sdb1` and `lvextend -l +100%FREE <your_volume_name>`.

Background info: in RHEL6 and previous, RedHat suggested to create a "Protective MBR" to prevent old OSes from modifying the LVM metadata. This means that LVM physical volumes where partition-based, rather than disk-based (as in your case). So, to extend the physical volume, you first need to extend the partition.

However, the `fdisk` version shipped with RHEL6 does not support simple partition resize. You need to remove and re-create the `sdb1` partition, which needs to be **absolutely identical** to what you now have (except for the lenght/size, of course). I *strongly* suggest you to use `fdisk -u`, which will give you partition size in sector number rather than cylinders.

Alternatively, you can use `parted` which *should* support partition resize (this feature is version-dependent and I do not remember if the one shipped with RHEL6 supports it).

**Be carefull: a wrongly-recreated partition will meen DATA LOSS.** I suggest you practicing on a test virtual machine before doing that in producion.

Comment: This sounds like a tricky situation because sometime ago i tried to do exactly that and i ended up loosing all data. That is why i created an lvm volume. is it possible to create a new paertition /dev/sdb2 and add it to lvm in order to expand total size?

Comment: @Meni sure: you can add a new partition and extend the physical volume but, while simpler, this will be somewhat more confusing/difficult to manage in the future. However it is the only possible approach if you don't want to delete/resize your current partition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a pvresize to allow LVM to recognise the additional disk. Its as simple as pvrsize /path/to/blockdevice

Answer (score 0):

@shodanshok thank you for pointing me to the right direction

Unfortunately my lvm volume was partition based and because i did not want to delete my current partition in order to resize it(once i lost all data) i have created another partition and used it to extend the lvm.
so what i did was:
1) created a new partition with

`fdisk /dev/sdb`

2) i initialized a physical volume for lvm managing with:

`pvcreate /dev/sdb2`

3) i added the new physical volume to my lvm group with:

`lvextend /dev/backup/lv0 /dev/sdb2`

4) finaly i resized the filesystem with:

`resize2fs /dev/backup/lv0`